# Смещение SVG при анимации в Mozilla

Tags: css, svg, кроссбраузерность

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с проблемой.
Есть [верстка](http://verstka.test30.ru/evona/). Там кнопка Скачать. При наведении стрелка опускается вниз. В Хроме все окей. В Опере тоже. А в Мозиле происходит еле заметное (буквально 1px) смещение стрелки влево, из-за чего происходит маленький скачок, а также SVG становится не такой четкой. Почему такое может происходить?

Comment: Описанных проблем в Mozilla не обнаружил.

Comment: [Записал видео](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8N586BNak6ERTNwblRVcWF1ZWM/view) (особенно видно в момент, когда стрелка прыгает наверх)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что при анимации браузер меняет режим отрисовки вектора с "красивого" на "для анимации".

**Решение 1**

Укажите конкретно [режим прорисовки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering):

```
<svg ...  shape-rendering="crispEdges" ... >
...
</svg>
```

**Решение 2**

Иконку нужно перерисовать.

Располагайте элементы svg строго по пикселям. Ваш документ просто набит дробными значениями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если числа, отвечающие за горизонтальные и вертикальные линии будут целые, у браузера не возникнет проблем к какому пикселю ее отнести:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решение 2 наверное не подойдет, так как дизайнер, который рисовал это дело, не будет все править, а этих SVG море на сайте будет..
А Решение 1 не помогло, к сожалению..

Comment: @АлександрБелькевич, cтранно, в FF 52 `shape-rendering` на вашем сайте решает проблему, проверьте

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Vm6a010Hog8XrZ неа, не решило.. С shape-rendering стрелки получаются какие-то узкие до того, как наведешь на кнопку..

Comment: @АлександрБелькевич, Попробуйте другие [режимы прорисовки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering)

Comment: Пробовал. optimizeSpeed совсем гадко показывает, geometricPrecision края делает рваными... ну auto по умолчанию..

Comment: @АлександрБелькевич, самое главное - стрелка-то не прыгает? Если нет, то режим сглаживания не меняется, а значит можно подобрать режим, который был до этого в статике.

Comment: Да в том то и прикол, что все равно скачок остается..)